# Реализация одного интерфейса в двух классах. Один унаследован у другого. Java

Tags: java, интерфейс

Проблема состоит в том, что никак не выходит реализовать один и тот же интерфейс в дух классах одновременно. К примеру, есть класс "Point2D" который реализует интерфейс "Comparable< Point2D>", у него унаследован класс "Point3D", в котором хотелось бы написать реализацию интерфейса "Comparable< Point3D>".

Не предоставляется возможным, разные аргументы. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Возможно, не стоит наследовать Point3D от Point2D? ПОпробуйте вместо этого оба класса унаследовать от Point и в каждом классе имплементировать Comparable. При этом Point этот интерфейс не должен имплементировать

Answer (score 1):

Вам правильно советует @ЮрийСПб.
Давайте посмотрим и проведем небольшой анализ на совместимость с SOLID. А конкретнее с [S- single responsibility principle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и [L- Liskov substitution principle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Вариант 1.

```
public abstract class Point{

}

public class Point3D implements Comparable<Point3D>{

  ....

  public int compareTo(Point2D anotherPoint)
    {
        ....
    }
}


public class Point2D implements Comparable<Point2D>{

  .....

  public int compareTo(Point2D anotherPoint)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Вариант 2. (Допустим такой вариант)

```
public class Point2D implements Comparable<Point2D>{

  .....

  public int compareTo(Point2D anotherPoint)
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class Point3D extends Point2D implements Comparable<Point3D>{

  ....

  public int compareTo(Point2D anotherPoint)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

1. По принципу единственной ответственности. Классы реализованные по варианту 1 не противоречат ему потому что нет необходимости думать за методы предка.
2. По принципу Лисков. Поскольку вы наследуете 3D от 2D в варианте 2. Ваше приложение не должно менять поведение заменой предка потомком. Этого у вас не получится поскольку `compareTo` методы различны.

PS. Собственно постановка Лисков в принципах SOLID очень сильно напрягает по поводу наследования классов и наследовать просто так желания не возникает.

Answer (score 0):

Суть в том, что вы пытаетесь реализовать один и тот же интерфейс дважды.

Смотрите, если

```
public class Point2D implements Comparable<Point2D>
```

и в то же время

```
public class Point3D extends Point2D
```

то Point3D уже имплементирует `Comparable<Point2D>`.

Это не единственная проблема, с которой можно столкнуться, используя интерфейс Comparable. Но всё можно решить, используя Comparator. Как-то так:

```
class Point3DComparator implements Comparator<Point3D> {     
    public int compare(Point3D a, Point3D b){
        //Ваш код здесь
    }
}
```

Ну, а дальше методы sort() самых разных коллекций все (ну или почти все, не помню) принимают в качестве аргумента такой кастомный компаратор и сортируют без проблем.

Comment: решение "в лоб" проблемы, которой следовало бы вообще избежать: Point3D не должна наследоваться от Point2D, это разные сущности. И чем дальше зайдет разработка - тем больше будет понятно, что это архитектурный недочет. Который со временем покрывается костылями в виде "ну, если не получается Comparable, сделаем Comparator" и так далее.